What is the translation of this quote by Plato?
I'm reading the book La porte des rêves by French writer Marcel Schwob.
In his third short story, he uses the following quote by Plato as an epigraph:

Tὴν ψυχὴν, ’Aγάθωνα ϕτλὼν, ὲπ χε λε λεσɩν ἔσχoν “Hλθε γἁρ ὴ τλήuων, ὡς
δɩα ησoµένη.
PLATON.


There is no translation available in French. Do you happen to know what it means?

Did you type that in or copy and paste it from somewhere? It's so full of typos as to be incomprehensible.

@TKR Thanks for letting me know. I took a print screen, is it understandable now?

Nope, your source material is off. Brianpck has it right. Interestingly, the web version on Project Gutenberg has the correct Greek.

@cmw Thanks, I didn't have a clue. I got this version on Anna's Archive.

This is a horribly garbled transcription of one of Plato's epigrams. Based on the strange images in the text and the nonsensical substitution of τ for ι (for instance), it seems likely that this was copied from an unedited OCR of the scanned Greek text.

Τὴν ψυχὴν Ἀγάθωνα φιλῶν ἐπὶ χείλεσιν ἔσχον·
ἦλθε γὰρ ἡ τλήμων ὡς διαβησομένη.

Here is Edmond's translation, revised by Cooper:

When I kiss Agathon my soul is on my lips, where it comes, poor thing,
hoping to cross over.

A more literal translation:

Kissing Agathon, I had [my] soul on [my] lips, for it came, wretched, as if it would walk across [future participle].

The authenticity of this epigram is quite doubtful, as Cooper notes in his introduction, since the Agathon likely referred to (who also appears in Plato's Symposium) is about two decades older than Plato.

This is an interesting case where a literal translation actually seems to give the sense better.
